# animated Plot using FuncAnimation give a blank graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a animated graph using matplotlib's FuncAnimation class. I want to plot the fermi() function with a different temperature value `T` at each frame. But the plot give a blank graph, why?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

# Fermi-Dirac Distribution
def fermi(E: float, E_f: float, T: float) -> float:
    k_b = 8.617 * (10**-5) # eV/K
    return 1/(np.exp((E - E_f)/(k_b * T)) + 1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()


# Temperature values
T = np.linspace(100, 1000, 10)

# Get colors from coolwarm colormap
colors = plt.get_cmap('coolwarm', 10)

# Create variable reference to plot
f_d, = ax.plot([], [], linewidth=2.5)
# Add text annotation and create variable reference
temp = ax.text(1, 1, '', ha='right', va='top', fontsize=24)

# Animation function
def animate(i):
    x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
    y = fermi(x, 0.5, T[i])
    f_d.set_data(x, y)
    f_d.set_color(colors(i))
    temp.set_text(str(int(T[i])) + ' K')
    temp.set_color(colors(i))

# Create animation
ani = FuncAnimation(fig=fig, func=animate, frames=range(len(T)), interval=500, repeat=True)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust the range of the axes of the animation graph to the data you want to use and the graph will be created. If you modify that point, the animation will be created. Since my environment is jupyterlab, I have installed additional libraries, so please remove them if you don't need them.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
# Jupyter lab and GIF create
# from IPython.display import HTML
# from matplotlib.animation import PillowWriter

# Fermi-Dirac Distribution
def fermi(E: float, E_f: float, T: float) -> float:
    k_b = 8.617 * (10**-5) # eV/K
    return 1/(np.exp((E - E_f)/(k_b * T)) + 1)

fig = plt.figure() # update
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 1), ylim=(0, 10)) # update
# Temperature values
T = np.linspace(100, 1000, 10)

# Get colors from coolwarm colormap
colors = plt.get_cmap('coolwarm', 10)

# Create variable reference to plot
f_d, = ax.plot([], [], linewidth=2.5)
# Add text annotation and create variable reference
temp = ax.text(1, 1, '', ha='right', va='top', fontsize=24)

# Animation function
def animate(i):
    x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
    y = fermi(x, 0.5, T[i])
    f_d.set_data(x, y)
    f_d.set_color(colors(i))
    temp.set_text(str(int(T[i])) + ' K')
    temp.set_color(colors(i))

# Create animation
anim = FuncAnimation(fig=fig, func=animate, frames=10, interval=500, repeat=True) # range(len(T))

# plt.close()
# HTML(anim.to_html5_video())
# anim.save('animate_test.gif', writer='pillow')
```

[image]

Comment: I tried it on jupyter notebook with your codes, but get RuntimeError: Requested MovieWriter (ffmpeg) not available. Any ideas what's wrong? Thanks!

Comment: If you have already installed ffmpeg and get an error, please refer to SO for a [solution](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+animation+save+ffmpeg+error+site:stackoverflow.com&sxsrf=ALeKk00g6strLzjDDnVrOmL9b-X0UhRp6A:1608688685477&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwib_pqtgOPtAhXOdXAKHaIxBJsQrQIoBHoECAwQBQ).